# How to solve the limit of a succession on this particular circumstances?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Given this limit
$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{\frac{\sqrt{16n^2+3}}{(1+a_n)n+5cos n}=\frac{7}{6}}$ 
I need to calculate this one :
$\displaystyle\lim_{n \to{+}\infty}{a_n}$

Any ideas of how to solve it. Thanks!!!

Comment: Hint: Divide top and bottom by $n$, let $n$ get big. Top approaches $4$. Term $(5\cos n)/n$ at the bottom dies. So for large $n$, $4/[(1+a_n)]$ is very close to $7/6$, and therefore $\dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  write
$$
{\sqrt{16n^2+3}\over (1+a_n) n +5\cos n}
= {n\cdot\sqrt{16+{3\over n^2} }\over n\cdot\bigl( (1+a_n)+{5\cos n\over n}\bigr)}
= {\sqrt{16+{3\over n^2} }\over (1+a_n)+{5\cos n\over n}}.
$$
Then note
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
 {\sqrt{16+{3\over n^2} }\over (1+a_n)+{5\cos n\over n}} ={4\over 1+\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n}.
$$

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much. I have a test tomorrow, and this exercise was killing me!